# CSS Sidebar - content area needs margin, but the width goes outside the frame with scroller

Tags: html, css

I've implemented my first sidebar design, but I came across a little problem.
My sidebar and content looks fine, however, there's a scroll-x bar that goes outside the frame.

This happened because I couldn't align both sidebar and content area to the left so they fit together, so I used `position: fixed` on the sidebar and then `margin-left: 200px;` on content area (Note: 200px is the width of the sidebar)

Here's an example of how I've implemented the sidebar:

http://jsfiddle.net/rWj95/11/

As you can see, there's a scroll-x. Even if I will disable the scroll-x, there will still be space left and the content will just go there.

Is there a way to properly implement the sidebar, so the width sizes will fit into the frame without going outside of it?

There's a live example: http://goo.gl/lFDQgl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width:100%` from #content to remove the scroll bar.

Now your #content will fill the remaining area on the page rather than taking up a 100% relative width of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc()` to properly align the `#content`

```
#content {
   width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

`200px` is the width of sidebar. So you need to subtract `200px` from `100%` of the parent width.

Comment: You're over thinking it. calc() has spotty performance on any web browser lower than IE10. If you simply don't include width, it will default to `auto` and fill the remaining space (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the overflows by exchanging the margin for padding on `.content` and add

```
 *, *:before, *:after {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

to the top of your styles. See @ http://jsfiddle.net/84Nz4/

Comment: Like aniskhan said, you have to account for the 200px width of your sidebar in addition to the 100% width of your content. Above is one way of doing that.